# SharePoint 2010 Strips my CSS

Tags: 2010, css, html

I was able to add in custom CSS using the "Edit HTML" option using these:

-float
-margin-right
-padding-left
-text-align

however, it modifies and removes my "border-left" that I add. Is this a common thing with borders using css within the regular content editing area? Or does it just hate me?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the page. Publishing type pages will typically remove HTML modifications, but Web Part Pages will allow them. To make custom CSS work, put the CSS into a file, upload it to a document library, insert a Content Editor Web Part into the page and reference the CSS file from there.